# SQL Выборка в начале по id, потом по имени

Tags: c#, mysql, запрос

Подскажите пожалуйста. Нужно выбрать с БД MySQL сначало по id, потом по поиску из textbox

Если выбрать все данные по ID то

```
string sql1 = string.Format("Select * From hospital.person Where id_Departament = @id_Departament");
```

код выбирает всё, но если я использую поиск :

```
 string Hospital_sql1_OKPO = string.Format("Select * From hospital.person WHERE CONCAT(`FIO`,`Position`,`Cabinet`) like '%" + TXB_Search_Person.Text.ToString() + "%' ");
```

он ищет без учёта id по всей БД, но мне нужно что он искал конкретно с учетом id
Как это можно в запросе реализовать?

Comment: дописать `and id=XX`

Comment: Не надо "сначала" и "потом". Искать нужно сразу то, что требуется.

Comment: зачем вам проверять какой то текст, если у вас есть id?